# Jquery DatePicker Set Pericular range

Tags: jquery, datepicker

how to set Jquery DatePicker as custom date like (01/02/2015) as Start date and 31/05/2015 as End date. and also not selected passed date from startdate .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a specific date range with jQuery datepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922184/create-a-specific-date-range-with-jquery-datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: new Date(2015, 2, 1), maxDate: new Date(2015, 5, 31) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
 $( "#from" ).datepicker({
          minDate: new Date('02/01/2015'),
          maxDate: new Date('05/31/2015'),

    });
```

```js
$( "#from" ).datepicker({
      minDate: new Date('02/01/2015'),
      maxDate: new Date('05/31/2015'),
     
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
```

Comment: @jigarPatel You welcome bro and you may appreciate it by marking it as answer and upvote :).